# How can there be so many register variables, with such a limited number of registers?

Tags: c, variables, assembly, microprocessors

I was fooling around with C and I realized, by rights, if I declared a bunch of register variables, wouldn't the values be overwritten? From what I can tell from assembly, there aren't a ton of registers in the microprocessor, not enough to satisfy the demand I created. How does C keep all the values?

Comment: `register` it is just a hint to the compiler. It is up to the latter to satisfy your desire or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no requirement that all variables declared with `register` must be kept in CPU registers.

Here's what the C standard says:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class
>   specifier register suggests that access to the object be as fast as
>   possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is
>   implementation-defined.

Reference: ISO C11 [N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.7.1 paragraph 6. Note that it doesn't even mention CPU registers.

A conforming compiler could simply ignore all `register` keywords (aside from imposing some restrictions on taking the address of `register` objects).

In practice, most compilers will simply place as many `register` variables in CPU registers as they can.

And in fact a modern optimizing compiler is likely to be better at register allocation than most programmers are -- especially since they can recompute register mappings every time you recompile your program after modifying it.

The common wisdom these days is that the `register` keyword doesn't provide much benefit.

Answer (score 5):

Old compiler would allocate as many registers to `register` variables as they could (in some cases, this number was 0) and allocate the remaining variables on the stack.

Modern compilers generally ignore the `register` keyword.  They employ sophisticated *register allocators* that automatically keep as many variables in registers as possible.

The only effect of `register` you can rely on is that you get a diagnostic message if you try to take the address of a register variable.  Otherwise, register variables behave just like automatic variables do.

Comment: Source for the second paragraph?

Comment: @JobHunter69 E.g. [here](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2012-July/051907.html) is a reference for LLVM.  The part about register allocators is taught at university.

Answer (score 2):

`register` is a hint that the compiler *can* keep the variable in registers.  You can't force the compiler to use more registers than exist on the target architecture, for the obvious reason that it's impossible.

---

In C, the `register` keyword simply means that the variable's address can't be taken.  This stops you from doing anything that would prevent the compiler keeping it in a register, but doesn't *require* it to be in a register.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration

> The register specifier is only allowed for objects declared at block scope, including function parameter lists. It indicates automatic storage duration and no linkage (which is the default for these kinds of declarations), but additionally hints the optimizer to store the value of this variable in a CPU register if possible. Regardless of whether this optimization takes place or not, variables declared register cannot be used as arguments to the address-of operator, cannot use alignas (since C11), and register arrays are not convertible to pointers.

It hasn't really done anything for years: Optimizing compilers already keep vars in regs whenever possible.  For vars that are global or have had their address taken, then maybe only for part of a function, storing the result back to memory if the variable can't be optimized away.

---

BTW, `register` was officially deprecated in C++, and C++17 actually removed it from the language.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration.

---

Related: GNU C has `register int foo asm("eax");` (or whatever other register), but even that is only *guaranteed* to have an effect when used as an operand to an inline-asm statement when used for local variables.  In current GCC versions, it does cause the compiler to use that register for the variable, unless it needs to spill / reload it to stack memory across function calls or whatever.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html

But in GNU C, you can use *global* register variables, where a register is dedicated to a global for the entire life of your program, hurting optimization of code that isn't using that variable.  It's an interesting option but not one you should use.

Answer (score 1):

C was designed to allow a compiler to generate assembly code for a function while it was being parsed, rather than having to read an entire function, examine it, and then produce code afterward.  A compiler that has parsed a program as far as:

```
int test(void)
{
  int x=0,y=0;
  int *p = &y;

  while(x < 10)
  {
    x++;
    foo();
    x++;
    *p *= 3;
    x++;
    bar();
    ...
```

would have no way of knowing whether the value of `x` could be safely kept in a register across the call to `foo` and/or the operation on `*p` or whether it might be possible for `foo` to alter the value of `x`.

The purpose of the `register` keyword was effectively to tell the compiler that it would be *safe* keep the value of an object in a register across function calls or operations that write to pointers, even if it hasn't seen everything that code might do with the object.  Such a meaning could be useful even today if passing the object's address to a nested function weren't a constraint violation, but a compiler was allowed to assume that in any context where a named-object lvalue was used, all operations would involve that named-object lvalue.  If an object's address is never taken, no qualifier would be needed to invite such an assumption, but in cases where an object's address *is* taken but not persisted across conflicting operations involving the object, such a qualifier could give a compiler information it would otherwise not have.

Answer (score -1):

Variables are normally stored on the stack. That is, a block of memory. The value of a variable is normally loaded into a register for manipulation and moved back to the stack (saved) if another variable is to be manipulated. Often the variable isn't even loaded into a register, it is manipulated on the stack.

Comment: That sometimes happens if you disable optimizations, on architectures like x86 that allow memory operands for most instructions.  Most of the other architectures in use today are load/store machines where only load and store instructions can access memory.  Even on x86, normal compilers optimize away the stack space for automatic-storage variables whenever possible.  Anyway, this answer doesn't even mention the `register` keyword.  You seem to just be describing how code not using `register` compiles with optimization disabled.  But IIRC, `register` can get `gcc -O0` to keep a var in regs.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes i did not understand the question because i never heard the term "register" variable before and thought that was just his wording. I'll have to play with this type of variable myself cause iv never used it.

Comment: You don't need to, the keyword isn't useful with modern optimizing compilers.